# Excel Formula: Reference a cells value whilst maintaining original cell reference

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Sorry for the hash of a title. Not sure how to explain this...
I have a cell that now stores a value of the Row kind of like a counter.
I need to extend a formula to now account for the number now stored in Cell A30.
My current formula is as follows:

=SUMIFS(J7:**J30**,K7:K**30**,">="&B38,K7:K**30**,"<="&C38, C7:C**30**, "FALSE")

The numbers in bold need to pull the value from Cell A30. Is this possible?

Comment: so you want all the `30`s to change to the value in A30?

Comment: you missed one. `J7:J**30**` needs to be included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the non volatile INDEX:

```
=SUMIFS(J7:INDEX(J:J,A30),K7:INDEX(K:K,A30),">="&B38,K7:INDEX(K:K,A30),"<="&C38, C7:INDEX(C:C,A30), "FALSE")
```

What this does is create a range reference form row 7 to the row indicated in A30 for each of the referenced columns.

For Example:

If `A30` has `200` as a value:

```
J7:INDEX(J:J,A30)
```

Would reference the range `J7:J200`

Comment: By doing this, every cell in each referenced column gets highlighted, is that correct?

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking.  This causes the ranges to go from row 7 to the row specified in A30 for each of the columns referenced in the formula.

Comment: Its okay, the formula works. Its just it highlights the whole column now instead of just Cells J7:J31 for instance. It does exactly as you said though. Thank you very much for this. It really is appreciated